# Using gitlab ci with docker compose leaves me with container generated folders gitlab can't remove

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to set up gitlab ci using the method documented [here](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-shell-executor) and testing a rails 4 app with it.

The problem I'm having is that the test will run once and build the image and containers, but when I try to run the test again it will fail with:

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.1.3 (a470667)
Using Shell executor...
Running on ubuntu-lon1-01...
Fetching changes...
warning: failed to remove tmp/miniprofiler

ERROR: Build failed: exit status 1
```

I think this is because the tmp folder is generated when you run the app a first time and is owned by root in the container.

[image]

This is the `gitlab.ci.yml` I'm currently using but I've tried lots of different versions all with the same result:

```
before_script:
  - docker info

build_image:
  stage: test
    script:
    -  docker-compose build
    -  docker-compose run web rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test
    -  docker-compose run web bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
    -  docker-compose up -d
    -  docker-compose run web bundle exec rspec
    -  docker-compose stop
```

I thought I may be able to delete the folder using the `after_script` but that doesn't work with the shell setup.

I'm not sure how to handle this. I think I need to either delete it on exit or change the permissions so it can be deleted.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.1

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential \
    && apt-get install -y apt-utils \
    && apt-get install -y libqt4-webkit libqt4-dev xvfb \
    && apt-get install -y wget \
    && apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-contrib \
    && apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev \
    && apt-get install -y imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN gem install foreman

WORKDIR /tmp
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/
```

And my docker-compose:

```
db:
  image: postgres:9.4
  ports:
    - "5432"
web:
  build: .
  command: foreman start -f Procfile.dev
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  stdin_open: true
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
```

Googling I can't seem to find anyone that's having the same issue so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the same setup using docker in docker? Since it suggest either shell or docker in docker. Would not fix your current issue, but i had that working before.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought I may be able to delete the folder using the after_script but that doesn't work with the shell setup.

I had the same issue and solved it by adding this to `.gitlab.ci.yml`

```
after_script:
  - docker-compose run web rm -rf tmp/
```

(Using shell runner with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.7.1)